# How to turn a linked group into independent objects?

Tags: export, file-format, linked-data, collada, groups

I created a group and added objects to it,
then Add -> Group Instance. How to turn this linked instance into
a completely independent, ungrouped "deep" copy of the objects in the group?

I've tried the options I get by RMB on the outliner, to no avail.

PS: I need this to export collada; the exporter code won't output the objects within a group if they're linked/instantiated from another scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make objects instantiated by group to be real ones.

While group instance selected, execute Make Duplicates Real operator (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> if in 2.79 or prior) to make objects from group as real ones. You can now deal with them as with meshes, because they already are.

Then you can run Make Single User operator from Object menu (or press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Object Data* if in 2.79 or prior) to make these objects use their own mesh datablock (if there is needed possibilty to edit them individually).

---

While this will work, it has it downsides:

#### Pros

1. Make objects from group finally editable (sometimes may be useful)

#### Cons

1. Additional geometry will be added that can lower scene processing or rendering time.
2. Additinal objects will appear in Outliner (if objects were made to use their own mesh datablocks), so in case of there are many objects in the scene, you may want to avoid this so not to slow down 3D View.

Comment: minor suggestion: you meant lowercase U key.

Comment: This works. PS: the first step is already enough for a collada export to include the data. The second step of making the link data local just duplicates the data in the export which may be useful for locality and individual edits, as mentioned.

Comment: whats the menu action of ctrl + shift + a ? Probably the shortcut is different now in blender 2.8 ?

Comment: @igrek in 2.8 most of shortcuts from previous versions were dropped. This operator though has its shortcut In 2.8, now it's Ctrl+A (same as for applying transform)